# unable to create a Xamarin Account for student

Tags: android, xamarin, account, dreamspark

I am unable to create a Xamarin Student Account, Although i have my Dream spark Account. After logging in my dreamspark account, whenever i click on get xamarin, it redirects me to the same page and disables the link, I am attaching the snapshot of my dreamspark account. I have downloaded the Xamarin studio but it shows a login screen whenever i start the emulator. Need your guidance, Thanks a lot!

[image: Dreamspark Account Snapshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser is blocking the pop-up, just click the red X window inside the URL bar and choose to show pop-up and retry. Also it may ask for a VAT number for a student account, just enter N/A which solved it for me

Comment: yeah, I did that, but still i am unable to create an account because it is requiring credit card information and about $1,998.00 are there that i have to pay to them :(

Comment: Is it asking you for this within the browser or within Xamarin? A discount of the full price for Android and iOS should be applied to it but I think it does still require card details. It looks like your discount is yet to be applied though as the green "get xamarin" button will say "you have xamarin" once it's applied.

Comment: @TryCatch there's a student discount being applied so you pay nothing for it, the -1998.00 is the discount as the price would be $1998 without the student discount. It's a 12 month subscription so the card details is for renewal after that

Comment: Yes Bro, It Created my Account I just Placed **N/A** in the Text Boxes where it was asking for credit card information..  Thanks!!